# Detection and localisation of peaks in the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

Here, is the Input Image:

[image: Input Image]

Here, is what I want:

[image: Desired Output]

Note that I am interested in finding out the local co-ordinates of the red points and these red points have been manually done. I want an algorithm to automate this.

I have tried template matching but have I guess have not been able to implement it properly since I did not get any meaningful output. I got the same input as output.

I am very new to OpenCV and your help is highly appreciate. Do share your code as well :)

Comment: There no complete algorithm for your task in OpenCV. You can threshold your image, then in each column find bottom location of non zero point and find minimum value in some window.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the peaks and the minimas that separate them are always placed at some defined range of the image you can remove everything from the thresholded image that hinders you of easily detecting the peaks. I'm not sure if the rules for separation are the right ones for you, because you only shared one picture. But you can tune this to your needs.

Remark: In order to reliably detect such features under different conditions (lighting, object placement, etc.) you will need many more sample images. Perhaps you may come to the conclusion that it is beneficial to invest some more research and train a ML model.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread('img.png')
h, w, _ = img.shape

min_x = int(w * 0.01)  # margin left
max_x = int(w * 0.99)  # margin right
min_y = int(h * 0.50)  # margin top
max_y = int(h * 0.95)  # margin bottom
dy = int(h * 0.20)  # height of region of interest (ROI) window

# thresholding
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# remove margins
cv2.rectangle(thresh, (0, 0), (w, min_y), 0, -1)
cv2.rectangle(thresh, (0, max_y), (w, h), 0, -1)
cv2.rectangle(thresh, (0, 0), (min_x, h), 0, -1)
cv2.rectangle(thresh, (max_x, 0), (w, h), 0, -1)

# get maximum y of contour and cut out ROI window in order to separate plants
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
m = max([p[0][1] for p in np.concatenate(contours)])
cv2.rectangle(thresh, (0, 0), (w, m - dy), 0, -1)

# get contours of separated plants and filter out smaller artefacts
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cc = [c for c in contours if 100 < cv2.contourArea(c)]
cv2.drawContours(img, cc, -1, (0, 0, 255))

# get peak for each separated contour
for c in cc:
    p = max([p[0] for p in c], key=lambda i: i[1])
    cv2.circle(img, p, 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)
```

Output:

[image]